# Base64 Decoding results contain unknown characters

Tags: base64

I have base64 encoded text and I try to decode it but when I decode it, it contains some unknown characters. But the interesting part is, decoded text contains that I need data. So just I need to remove unknown characters and I need to split the data.

Do you have any suggestion to escape this unknown characters?

E.g base64 data:

`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`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a base64 encoded **protobuf** data. you can decode it from https://protogen.marcgravell.com